# How to appear different dropdown group list on onChange of HTML <SELECT> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am a novice in JavaScript and jQuery. I provide my HTML code below. I want to make two group of selection in my `<SELECT>` tags; e.g. Central and Northern. Both `<SELECT>` tag will have different sub list. For instance, Central will have A, B and C. While Northern will have 1, 2 and 3.

I have do try and error by putting JavaScript code in my HTML as below, unfortunately nothing change and I thing it have problem somewhere. Please help me by correcting my code. TQ

*At First Step, user will click whether Central or Northern.*

[image]

*Then system are able to different between Central and Northern. Both should have different list group.
In my case below, it is error somewhere, should be only One dropdown.*

[image]

*My Code as below*

```
<label>Region :</label>
<select class="custom-select form-control">
<option value="">Select Region</option>
<option value="central" id="Central">Central</option>
<option value="northern" id="Northern">Northern</option>
</select>

<label>Node Pair :</label>
<select onchange="getCentral(this)">
<option value="">Select Central</option>
<option value="A">A</option>
<option value="B">B</option>
<option value="C">C</option>
</select>

<select onchange="getNorthern(this)">
<option value="">Select Northern</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somthing like this with jquery should do the trick:

In your `<head></head>` section put this:

```
    <style>
        .subCat {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
```

And in your `<body></body>` replace your html for this:

```
    <label>Region :</label>
    <select id="selRegion" class="custom-select form-control">
        <option value="">Select Region</option>
        <option value="central" id="Central">Central</option>
        <option value="northern" id="Northern">Northern</option>
    </select>

    <label>Node Pair :</label>
    <select id="selCentral" onchange="getCentral(this)" class="subCat">
        <option value="">Select Central</option>
        <option value="A">A</option>
        <option value="B">B</option>
        <option value="C">C</option>
    </select>

    <select id="selNorthern" onchange="getNorthern(this)" class="subCat">
        <option value="">Select Northern</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>

    <script>
        $(function() {
            $("#selRegion").change(function() {
                $(".subCat").hide();

                var val = $(this).val();
                if(val == "central") {
                    $("#selCentral").show();
                } else if(val == "northern") {
                    $("#selNorthern").show();
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: By the way, are you specialist in Javascript or jQuery? Because I have one question regarding that language. I will post later on.

Comment: @mastersuse im senior fullstack developper, i don't know everything but can definitely help. ;)